# How to add a formfield with useFormik in react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to add a formfield with fieldId="selectedIds". i have the code like below,

```
const {handleSubmit, values, setFieldTouched, setFieldValue } =
    useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            selectedIds:[],
        },
        validationSchema,
        onSubmit: //some logic,
    });
 
const field = <FormField name="selectedIds" display="none"/>;


return (
    {field}
    <Table />
);
```

but this gives error like below,

Cannot destructure property 'validationSchema' of '(0 , formik__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useFormikContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

I am new to using FormFields and formik. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use yup in this case:

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  lastName: yup.string().required(),
});
```